# TIKZ with the siamltex1213 class

Tags: tikz-pgf, document-classes

`pdflatex` does not work with `siamltex1213` class as mentioned in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183134/how-to-use-latex-template-for-siam-papers).

Also TIKZ does not work with this class as mentioned [in this comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/238664/tikz-stacking-two-nodes-with-equal-width-without-double-drawing-the-overlapping#comment566526_238668).

Are there any workarounds for using TIKZ with the `siamltex1213` class?

Comment: I tried the document in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/258091/4427 after changing `standalone` with `siamltex1213`; compiling with `latex+dvips+ps2pdf` seems working quite well.

Comment: Are you asking because you want your self-compiled PDF to look like a SIAM paper, or because you want to include TikZ figures in the TeX sent to SIAM for production of the published version?

Comment: That comment does not really say TikZ is incompatible. Note that a comment or two later, the user just remarks that there are lots of issues switching to the class. That may well be messing things up generally and solving them may well sort out the TikZ, too. TikZ does not require pdfTeX for compilation in general. So if you are having a problem, we need a minimal example document that we can use to reproduce it.

Comment: The latest update (January 2016) of [SIAM's macros](https://www.siam.org/journals/auth-info.php) now offcially supports `pgfplots` and thus TikZ.